# Displaying multiple Items in the list to an ftp server Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to display multiple Items in the list and store it in the ftp server. So far I can only store the first index, now I want when the user decides to take multiple photos, they can be stored also on the ftp server. So may you please help how can I loop through photos file list and achieve this: Check my code below

```
 final photos = <File>[];

 Future<void> fileUpload() async {
    FTPConnect ftpConnect = FTPConnect('xxxxxxxx',
        user: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        pass: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        port: xx,
        //isSecured: false,
        debug: true);
    try {
      File fileToUpload =  await File(photos.first.path);
      await ftpConnect.connect();
      await ftpConnect.changeDirectory('public_html');
      await ftpConnect.changeDirectory('assets');
      await ftpConnect.changeDirectory('images');
      await ftpConnect.changeDirectory('app');
      await ftpConnect.sizeFile('$photos');
      await ftpConnect.rename('CAP4077791735949912884.jpg', 'laptop.jpg');
      await ftpConnect.uploadFile(fileToUpload);
      await ftpConnect.disconnect();
    } catch (e) {
      //error
      await _log('Error: ${e.toString()}');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Remove your credentails

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the code in the loop with the length of the list of `photos`.

```
final photos = <File>[];
for (File photo in photos) {
  // your code to upload file to the FTP server
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A loop will do the trick:

```
  Future<void> fileUpload() async {
   FTPConnect ftpConnect = FTPConnect('x.x.x',
      user: 'x',
      pass: 'x',
      port: 0,
      //isSecured: false,
      debug: true);
  try {
    File fileToUpload = await File(photos.first.path);
    await ftpConnect.connect();
    await ftpConnect.changeDirectory('public_html');
    await ftpConnect.changeDirectory('assets');
    await ftpConnect.changeDirectory('images');
    await ftpConnect.changeDirectory('app');
    await ftpConnect.sizeFile('$photos');
    await ftpConnect.rename('CAP4077791735949912884.jpg', 'laptop.jpg');
    photos.forEach((element) async {
      File _file = File(element.path);
      await ftpConnect.uploadFile(_file);
    });

    await ftpConnect.disconnect();
  } catch (e) {
    //error
    debugPrint(e.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Hooshyar, thank you for your response, but when I capture an Image again, It seems it cannot upload, It only uploads the first one

Comment: hello, you're welcome
that's because you initialize the photos list to [] each time state refreshes, you either need to declare photos variable somewhere independent of this screen state.

Comment: So where do you think I should declare it if not on this class?

Comment: That's a totally separate subject, but I think you can use the provider as a state management solution, then have the photos variable in the provider, and have some functions to assign value and clear it. 
the variable inside the provider will work like a global variable which will not change until you want to change.